# How to specify multiple values on siteSearch in google custom search api?

Tags: google-custom-search

I'm using the google custom search API and I want to create a search using the `siteSearch`:

https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=k&cx=cx&q=cocos2d&siteSearch=www.cocos2d-iphone.org&siteSearchFilter=i

This works fine (returns all the result only from the given website).

Then I want to specify TWO sites to search, so I tried to change this:

```
siteSearch=www.cocos2d-iphone.org
```

to one of these:

```
siteSearch=www.cocos2d-iphone.org www.XXXXXXXX.org
```

```
siteSearch=www.cocos2d-iphone.org|www.XXXXXXXX.org
```

```
siteSearch=www.cocos2d-iphone.org||www.XXXXXXXX.org
```

but none of them worked.

Comment: did you find any solution ? I am also facing similar problem.

Answer (score 7):

Currently I don't believe you can specify more site through the query param siteSearch.

nevertheless you can configure your Custom Search Engine here: https://www.google.com/cse/manage/all
in the "Site to search" area.

This also works for excluding, as you can read here: https://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2631038&topic=2601037&ctx=topic

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with the *as_sitesearch* parameter as that only accepts a single value. But you can achieve what you want with the *as_q* parameter, setting it to some value like: *"site:google.com OR site:microsoft.com"* - that will work in a similar way to [this search](https://www.google.es/search?q=test+site:www.google.com%20OR%20site:www.microsoft.com).

The *as_q* parameter is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results#Advanced_Search_Query_Parameters) as:

> The as_q parameter provides search terms to check for in a document.
>   This parameter is also commonly used to allow users to specify
>   additional terms to search for within a set of search results.
>   Examples   q=president&as_q=John+Adams

Comment: I have tried to use as_q to limit to multiple sites with every variation of syntax I can imagine, and can't make it work. Do you, by chance, have a live example - or a complete markup example I could look at?

Comment: Links are broken, seems like `as_q` is deprecated.

Comment: It's still documented at https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results#Advanced_Search_Query_Parameters

Comment: https://www.google.es/search?q=test+site:www.google.com%20OR%20site:www.microsoft.com works for me

Answer (score 0):

Use "space" as seperator

Below is sample PHP code which works for me

```
$url="https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=k&cx=cx&q=cocos2d&siteSearch=".urlencode("www.cocos2d-iphone.org www.XXXXXXXX.org")."&siteSearchFilter=i"
```

Thanks,
Ojal Suthar

Answer (score 0):

**`as_q` paramenter seems to be deprecated.** It is not even present in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list

---

Use the regular `q` parameter, as `siteSearch` works with a single url only.

You can do just like what @netgenius.com.uk said, but inside your query.

For instance, I want to search posts from Nasa about Mars:

```
q=planet mars site:twitter.com/nasa OR site:facebook.com/nasa
```

Full query would be something like:

[https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=planet mars site:twitter.com/nasa OR site:facebook.com/nasa&cx=foobar&key=barfoo&safe=off](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list)